# VHDL warning "Warning (13024): Output pins are stuck at VCC or GND" on crucial output

Tags: vhdl, synthesis, register-transfer-level

I'm currently working in a project where I must take a Fibonacci algorithm high level description (C) and transform it in a RTL module written in VHDL. To do so, one would need to transform such high level description in synthetizable VHDL code, i.e., one would have to write a VHDL code for a datapath and a finite state machine (FSM), in a methodology widely known in IC prototyping.

I described the datapath and the FSM in two separate files and instanciated them in a third as VHDL COMPONENTs, defining the Fibonacci module. Using the Quartus II software, "Analysis & Synthesis" succeeds with no erros and with the very annoying warning "Warning (13024): Output pins are stuck at VCC or GND". What makes this warning truly annoying is that it shows up for the most crucial output of the Fibonacci module, wich is its final result. This output is called "d_o" in my code.

The "data_o" output pin comes from the datapath component, wich is also descripted using COMPONENTs such as adders, subtractors, registers and multiplexers. Compiling (Analysis & Sysnthesis) the datapath alone the warning shows up again for the same output.

I realy don't know what is wrong with my code, hope you guys can help me. The code is presented below:

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL; 
USE IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

ENTITY datapath IS
GENERIC (NUMBITS    : NATURAL := 32);
PORT (  SIGNAL rst          : IN STD_LOGIC;
        SIGNAL clk          : IN STD_LOGIC;

        ---Sinal de entrada---
        SIGNAL data_in      : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(NUMBITS-1 DOWNTO 0);

        ---Sinais de seleção---
        SIGNAL di_sel       : IN STD_LOGIC;
        SIGNAL nf_sel       : IN STD_LOGIC;
        SIGNAL na1_sel      : IN STD_LOGIC;
        SIGNAL na2_sel      : IN STD_LOGIC;
        SIGNAL io_sel       : IN STD_LOGIC;
        SIGNAL so0_sel      : IN STD_LOGIC;
        SIGNAL so1_sel      : IN STD_LOGIC;

        ---Sinais load---
        SIGNAL nf_ld        : IN STD_LOGIC;
        SIGNAL di_ld        : IN STD_LOGIC;
        SIGNAL na1_ld       : IN STD_LOGIC;
        SIGNAL na2_ld       : IN STD_LOGIC;
        SIGNAL do_ld        : IN STD_LOGIC;

        ---Sinais das comparações---
        SIGNAL di_eq_0      : OUT STD_LOGIC;
        SIGNAL di_eq_1      : OUT STD_LOGIC;

        ---Sinais de saída---
        SIGNAL irq_o        : OUT STD_LOGIC;
        SIGNAL status_o     : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 DOWNTO 0);
        SIGNAL d_o          : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(NUMBITS-1 DOWNTO 0));
END datapath;


ARCHITECTURE behavior OF datapath IS
---Componentes do datapath---   
COMPONENT somador
    GENERIC (NUMBITS    : NATURAL := 32);
    PORT (  SIGNAL x    : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(NUMBITS-1 DOWNTO 0);
            SIGNAL y    : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(NUMBITS-1 DOWNTO 0);
            SIGNAL XY   : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(NUMBITS-1 DOWNTO 0));
END COMPONENT;

COMPONENT subtrator
    GENERIC (NUMBITS    : NATURAL := 32);
    PORT (  SIGNAL x    : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(NUMBITS-1 DOWNTO 0);
            SIGNAL y    : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(NUMBITS-1 DOWNTO 0);
            SIGNAL XY   : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(NUMBITS-1 DOWNTO 0));
END COMPONENT;

COMPONENT reg
    GENERIC (NUMBITS    : NATURAL := 32);
    PORT( SIGNAL rst    : IN STD_LOGIC;
          SIGNAL clk    : IN STD_LOGIC;
          SIGNAL load   : IN STD_LOGIC;
          SIGNAL d      : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(NUMBITS-1 DOWNTO 0);
          SIGNAL q      : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(NUMBITS-1 DOWNTO 0));
END COMPONENT;

COMPONENT multiplexor2a1
    GENERIC (NUMBITS    : NATURAL := 32);
    PORT (  SIGNAL a    : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(NUMBITS-1 DOWNTO 0);
            SIGNAL b    : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(NUMBITS-1 DOWNTO 0);
            SIGNAL sel  : IN STD_LOGIC;
            SIGNAL f    : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(NUMBITS-1 DOWNTO 0));
END COMPONENT;

COMPONENT igual
    GENERIC (NUMBITS    : NATURAL := 32);
    PORT (  SIGNAL a    : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(NUMBITS-1 DOWNTO 0);
            SIGNAL b    : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(NUMBITS-1 DOWNTO 0);
            SIGNAL eq   : OUT STD_LOGIC);
END COMPONENT;

---Sinais de conexão---
SIGNAL mux2di           : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(NUMBITS-1 DOWNTO 0);
SIGNAL mux2nf           : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(NUMBITS-1 DOWNTO 0);
SIGNAL mux2na1          : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(NUMBITS-1 DOWNTO 0);
SIGNAL mux2na2          : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(NUMBITS-1 DOWNTO 0);

---Saidas dos registradores---  
SIGNAL nf_o             : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(NUMBITS-1 DOWNTO 0);
SIGNAL di_o             : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(NUMBITS-1 DOWNTO 0);
SIGNAL na1_o            : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(NUMBITS-1 DOWNTO 0);
SIGNAL na2_o            : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(NUMBITS-1 DOWNTO 0);

---Saidas do somador e do subtrator---
SIGNAL a_result         : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(NUMBITS-1 DOWNTO 0);
SIGNAL s_result         : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(NUMBITS-1 DOWNTO 0);

---Constatntes---   
SIGNAL one              : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(NUMBITS-1 DOWNTO 0);
SIGNAL zero             : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(NUMBITS-1 DOWNTO 0);

BEGIN
zero <= "00000000000000000000000000000000";
one  <= "00000000000000000000000000000001";

---Lógica para irq_o---
WITH io_sel SELECT
    irq_o <= '0' WHEN '0', '1' WHEN OTHERS;

---Lógica para status_o---
WITH so0_sel SELECT
    status_o(0) <= '0' WHEN '0', '1' WHEN OTHERS;
WITH so1_sel SELECT
    status_o(1) <= '0' WHEN '0', '1' WHEN OTHERS;

---Multiplexadores(4)---
mux1: multiplexor2a1 GENERIC MAP(NUMBITS) PORT MAP (data_in, s_result, di_sel, mux2di);
mux2: multiplexor2a1 GENERIC MAP(NUMBITS) PORT MAP (one, nf_o, nf_sel, mux2nf);
mux3: multiplexor2a1 GENERIC MAP(NUMBITS) PORT MAP (zero, na1_o, na1_sel, mux2na1);
mux4: multiplexor2a1 GENERIC MAP(NUMBITS) PORT MAP (a_result, di_o, na2_sel, mux2na2);

---Registradores(5)---  
d_i: reg GENERIC MAP (NUMBITS) PORT MAP (rst, clk, di_ld, mux2di, di_o);
na1: reg GENERIC MAP (NUMBITS) PORT MAP (rst, clk, na1_ld, mux2na1, na1_o);
na2: reg GENERIC MAP (NUMBITS) PORT MAP (rst, clk, na2_ld, mux2na2, na2_o);
nf:  reg GENERIC MAP (NUMBITS) PORT MAP (rst, clk, nf_ld, mux2nf, nf_o);
do:  reg GENERIC MAP (NUMBITS) PORT MAP (rst, clk, do_ld, nf_o, d_o);

---Somador---
a: somador GENERIC MAP(NUMBITS) PORT MAP (na1_o, na2_o, a_result);

---Subtrator---   
s: subtrator GENERIC MAP(NUMBITS) PORT MAP (di_o, one, s_result);

---Comparadores (2)---
eq0:  igual GENERIC MAP(NUMBITS) PORT MAP (di_o, zero, di_eq_0);
eq1:  igual GENERIC MAP(NUMBITS) PORT MAP (di_o, one, di_eq_1);
END ARCHITECTURE;
```

And the warning:

```
"Warning (13024): Output pins are stuck at VCC or GND"
```

Comment: I also get the same warning all the time. It seems that they don't make trouble and I always ignore them.

Comment: Important question is : did it work correctly in simulation? The message is telling you that (some of) the output bits are `1` or `0`. If that's because e.g. you're using signed and Fibonacci numbers never go -ve, that's OK. If it's because a mux sel is stuck so the output is always 1, you have a problem to fix.  Oh, and you might be surprised how high level a description will synth in VHDL these days...

Comment: It didn't work correctly in the simulation. The output (d_o) gets stuck in 0 (32 bits), therefor, not showing what it should show, wich is the fibonacci sequence. I don't a mux sel is stuck though, because the fsm compiles with no warnings or errors ant it appears to be changing the states correctly in the time chart. And about the level of the description, it has to be RTL, it's a course specification

Comment: Then you have to debug it. For every reg, mux etc, if the output is 0, are the inputs correct? Eventually you will get back to the fault. When it works in sim, then try synth again.

Answer (score 1):

This error is showing because one or more of your outputs are permanently high or low during the simulation. Usually this problem arises when testbench is not considering all outputs and some are assigned default values. If this is the case, this will not impact your design in anyway.

However, if another output that is being given valid input is stuck to 0 or one, than the code should be checked for errors. In that case, also edit your question to make it clear that code needs to checked for logical errors.

Answer (score 0):

Altera says this on this issue;

[image]